# How to copy a specific file from sub folders to one other folder

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I have a folder named Mods and in that folder I have:

- `root\sound\weapons\ak47\ak47_dist.wav`
- `root\sound\weapons\m1\m1_dist.wav`
- `root\sound\weapons\m4a1\m4a1_dist.wav`

etc...

In every `ak47`, `m1`, `m4a1`, etc. folders, I have 5 `.WAV` sound files.

I want to copy only the `*dist.wav` named sound files from every "weapon" named folder, and paste these sounds into a single folder with a batch file.

The batch file will be executed from the "Mods" folder which is outside `root\sound\weapons`, the new folder name is "distant sounds" inside the `Mods` folder.

How can i do that.

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know if it helped you resolve your issue? If so, feel free to check the little gray check mark to close it.

Answer (score 1):

> **How to copy a specific file from sub folders to one other folder**
>
> In every ak47, m1, m4a1 etc. folders, I have 5 sounds.
>
> I wan't to copy only the `*dist.wav` sounds from every weapon folder
>   and paste these sounds to a single folder with batch.

Below is an example of how you can do this from a batch script or from a copy and paste. Please read though everything and test to confirm all works as expected too.

### Command Prompt Copy and Paste

```
SET RootDir=C:\Sound\Weapons
SET CopyDir=C:\Path\Mods\Distant Sounds
IF NOT EXIST "%CopyDir%" MD "%CopyDir%"
SET CopyFname=*dist.wav
FOR /D %A IN ("%RootDir%\*") DO FOR %B IN ("%~A\%CopyFname%") DO ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%~B" "%CopyDir%\"
GOTO EOF
```

### Batch Script

```
@ECHO ON
SET RootDir=C:\Sound\Weapons
SET CopyDir=C:\Path\Mods\Distant Sounds
IF NOT EXIST "%CopyDir%" MD "%CopyDir%"
SET CopyFname=*dist.wav
FOR /D %%A IN ("%RootDir%\*") DO FOR %%B IN ("%%~A\%CopyFname%") DO ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%%~B" "%CopyDir%\"
GOTO EOF
```

**Notes:** Set the root directory, the copy directory, and the file name to copy in the `SET <variablename>=` part of the logic above.

### Further Reading and Resources

- [**XCOPY**](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)
- [**FOR**](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [**FOR /D**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)